# Can ios users connect and play with PC users?

Tags: steam, terraria, terraria-mobile

I have Terraria on Steam and on mobile, but I want to know if I can connect with PC users.

I believe my friend has accomplished this, but I do not know how. Is this possible? How do you do it if so?

Answer (score 2):

No you cannot connect between Terraria on PC and Terraria on mobile.

The simple reason for this is that the two games are completely different. As I'm sure you would know since you have both versions, there are many changes between the two games such as different enemies and items. It would be impossible for the two different games to be able to connect.